# YSlow: Avoid CSS Expressions called on CSS Parameter

Tags: css, expression, yslow

I ran my site through YSlow and received an F on "Avoid CSS Expressions" for CSS hrefs like this:

```
<link href="/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css?1420669254" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Does YSlow not like CSS parameters? Anything I can try to get this YSlow compliant?

Answer (score 1):

From the Yahoo best practices explanation of [CSS Expressions](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_expressions):

> CSS expressions are a powerful (and dangerous) way to set CSS
>   properties dynamically. They were supported in Internet Explorer
>   starting with version 5, but were deprecated starting with IE8.

Some options for dealing with this:

- Remove the link to the font awesome IE7 CSS file and don't worry about any IE7 specific support
- Dig into that CSS file to find and fix the CSS expressions (difficult)
- Ignore the bad YSlow grade for that component.